# Beginner on AWS got message that an SSL certificate has expired. Don't know root user information

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

I am a developer trying to help a customer who has lost their root access information.  I have full access except for root access.  I have developed a webhook that communicates between a catalog sales site and their CRM site.

It was working fine, until suddenly it started getting 500 error codes.  I tracked down that it was because the SSL certificate has expired.  How do I find out what SSL certificates exist and how to fix this problem.

One difficulty is that in order to request technical help, I must upgrade the support plan, which I am willing to do, but can only do this from the root access account.  In addition, I can't ask a question about how to reset the root account access unless I have the support plan.

We have the account number, BTW.  We are running an EC2 instance on an AWS Linux server.  Pointers to how to either get paid help or reset root access would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out destination needed to purchase a new certificate and all was well.  I thought the problem was on the sending end, but it was actually on the receiving.

Answer (score 0):

SSL certificates will be in one of 2 places:

- ACM for either CloudFront Distributions or Elastic Load Balancers.
- Locally on an EC2 Server if you connect directly to server.

If you need to connect to the EC2 server you will need to be able to connect via SSH or RDP depending on OS.

Regarding getting root access, you will need to attempt account recovery via AWS support. You'll be expected to provide proof that you own the account before they can reset these credentials for you.